# Excel vba pastespecial fails to paste all values when looping over two lists

Tags: vba, excel

I have two lists/columns in two different sheets that I want to loop over. Sheet2 (5000 rows and 11 columns) contains relevant information and list2/columnN contains text that I want to compare (if the same text string exists in sheet1 (300 rows, 1 column: list1/columnA).

When I get a match between list1 (value in columnA) and list2 (value in columnN) . I want to copy the whole row (the row where the match occured) in sheet2 and paste it in to a new sheet (sheet3). The goal with the code is to create Sheet3 containing all relevant information(i.e. X rows and 11 columns).

The code works when I run the code step-by-step. But when I run it, several rows does not get copied into the new sheet. It is like excel skips pasting/fails to loop over several rows.

I will attach my code below. I would appreciate if anyone could explain why it doesn't work and provide me with a solution.

```
Sub ReturnNewSheet()
Dim List1 As Range
Dim List2 As Range
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WS3 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set List1 = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Set List2 = Range("N2", Range("N2").End(xlDown))

Set WB1 = Workbooks("Workbook1")

Set WS3 = WB1.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set WS2 = WB1.Worksheets("sheet2")

CountOfagents = 0
Range("B2").Select

For Each Agent In List2
    For Each Relevantagent In List1
        If Agent = Relevantagent Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            WS3.Activate
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
            WS2.Activate
            'ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For

        End If

    Next Relevantagent

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next Agent

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to avoid `.Select` and `.Activate`. Create an object range/sheets each time instead.

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201611171056517462415) with suggestions on how to avoid .Select and .Activate, as mentioned by Ary!